# Eve framework: user restricted resource access

Tags: python, authentication, eve

I'm using Eve framework and I'm trying to use User-Restricted resource access as described in:
http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#user-restricted-resource-access

I'm doing something like:

```
class CustomAuth(TokenAuth):
    def check_auth(self, token, allowed_roles, resource, method):
        # Get user as an instance of UserResource.
        if user and hasattr(user, 'id'):
            self.set_request_auth_value(user['id'])
        request.authenticated_user = user
        ...
```

So, there are a few question from my side:

- Is it enough for using User-Restricted Resource Access?
- How this field adds into user created objects?
- Is this additional field called `id` in my user created objects? Is it possible to rename it?
- As I understand it should be named same as it's called in User resource. Is it true?
- Does this field (property) applies for newly created objects only? Is it possible to fetch previously created objects by current user following this way?

Well, I want to know an answers for my questions + clarify how it may be used.

Is it an expected way to extract it somehow in my hooks?

```
user_id = current_app.auth.get_request_auth_value()
current_app.data.driver.session.query(resource).find({'id': user_id})
```

Is this block of code from hook expected?
How it behaves if my requested resource has its own `id` field?

P.S. I was reading a post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35654252/7335432

Comment: Guys, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The user-restricted access feature prevents users from accessing records they didn't create. The set_request_auth_value() method does:

1) Upon making a POST request to create a record, it automatically adds a field specified as AUTH_FIELD (or auth_field if you only want to do it to a specific resource). So for example, if you declare in settings.py

```
AUTH_FIELD = "my_auth_field"
```

and then add

```
set_request_auth_value(user['id'])
```

to your authentication method, that means that your app creates a field "my_auth_field" that has its value set to whatever user["id"] is. So if you were to go into Mongo Compass or some other DBMS and manually inspect your records, you'd see a "my_auth_field" field in there.

2) On GET requests when you access those records, Eve checks the "my_auth_field" value against whatever user["id"] is, and only displays the records where "my_auth_field" is equal to user["id"]. Since this field is added automatically when you create a record using Eve, it effectively filters out everything that specific user didn't create.

So yes, it only applies to newly created objects. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "is it enough", but it doesn't look like 'user' is declared anywhere in your authentication class. You might wanna check out [this tutorial](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html#accounts-with-token-authentication) they do incorporating user restricted access into token authentication.